# Event listener set on the wrong elment

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why this javascript doesn't work:

```
var element = document.querySelector('#element1');
var button= document.querySelector('#button1');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element.doSomething();
});

var element = document.querySelector('#element2');
var button= document.querySelector('#button2');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element.doSomething();
});
```

Both of the buttons are doing something to "element2".

Is it something like the event listener keeps a pointer to the variable instead of its value ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Why the same name to both variables? The later one is overwriting the previously defined ones.

Comment: Related: [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your block-level code with an anonymous; self-executing function.

This is similar to when you wrap `{ /* {{code}} */ }` a block of code, with curly-braces,  in Java. You can have duplicate variables, as long as they exist in their own block.

That way, the variables can be the same. You should really create a separate function and pass in the selector IDs; especially if they are doing the same thing.

```js
(function() {
  HTMLDivElement.prototype.doSomething = function () { 
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML == 'Hello' ? 'Goodbye' : 'Hello';
  }
}());

(function() {
  var element = document.querySelector('#element1');
  var button = document.querySelector('#button1');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element.doSomething();
  });
}());

(function() {
  var element = document.querySelector('#element2');
  var button = document.querySelector('#button2');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element.doSomething();
  });
}());
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  border: thin solid black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div id="element1">?</div>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Button 1" />
<br />
<div id="element2">?</div>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Button 2" />
```

You should try this.

```js
function addButtonClick(btnSelectorId, elSelectorId) {
  document.querySelector(btnSelectorId).addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector(elSelectorId).doSomething();
  });
}

addButtonClick('#button1', '#element1');
addButtonClick('#button2', '#element2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have given same name to both the elements & buttons which is overwriting the previous one :

```
var element1 = document.querySelector('#element1');
var button1= document.querySelector('#button1');
button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element1.doSomething();
});

var element2 = document.querySelector('#element2');
var button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');
button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element2.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Yes I know, I am not asking to correct the code, but to understand why it doesn't work on a lower level

Comment: Yeah, the new value replaces the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referencing the `elment` variable *inside* your event handler functions. When you assign a  new value to `elment`, you change its value and this affects both handlers.

The solution: use a different variable name for each:

```
var element1 = document.querySelector('#element1');
var button = document.querySelector('#button1');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element1.doSomething();
});

var element2 = document.querySelector('#element2');
var button = document.querySelector('#button2');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element2.doSomething();
});
```

Or better yet, perhaps, do away with the closure variables altogether and just query as needed:

```
document.querySelector('#button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('#element1');

    element.doSomething();
});

document.querySelector('#button2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('#element2');

    element.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that the internal function is evaluated at the end of the "main" function ?

Comment: @Tribes No, the internal function is evaluated when a click event occurs, which could be seconds, minutes, or hours after your code originally runs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable for both the elements and so the last declared variable is the one that will be used.

For example:

```
x = "Hello";
x = "World";
console.log(x); //This will print out "World"
```

You need to declare them as different variables. Example with your code(Notice I changed the second element):

```
var elment = document.querySelector('#element1');
var button= document.querySelector('#button1');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    elment.doSomething();
});

var elment2 = document.querySelector('#element2'); //Changed to elment2
var button2 = document.querySelector('#button2'); //Changed to button2
button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    elment2.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Yes but 
x = "Hello";
console.log(x); //This will print out "Hello"
x = "World";
console.log(x); //This will print out "World"

Comment: @Tribes That's because you are writing the values to the console immediately. Event handlers do not execute immediately when you add them; they execute when the event happens.

Comment: @tribes the thing is the events are registered when the DOM is loaded, which gives the browser to replace the values :).

Comment: No. It will only print out the last declared since we are declaring it to a new value. So in the beginning the value was "Hello" and after we decleared "x" again, value is now "World" and so it will print out "World".